# Multiple Line Search in Notepad++

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

I'm looking for a way to identify a missing record within a record group in Notepad++.  Each record group begins and ends with a tilde.  However, some groups are missing the detail record (H1 record).  In the example below, I need to find the bold/italicized entries.

~H1~,10222,30333,JONES
MIDWEST EMERGENCY, 123456
~
~H1~,30334,3234543,SMITH
MIDWEST EMERGENCY,933233
~
***MIDWEST EMERGENCY,92345434***
~
~H1~,3232353434,232343534,HORST
MIDWEST EMERGENCY,223342545
~
***EASTERN EMERGENCY,2334333***
~
~H1~,3055543,33232322,VICE
SOUTHERN EMERGENCY,233446655
~

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
/~\n[A-Z]+[ ]+EMERGENCY[, ][0-9]+\n~/g
```

First match for "~", then newline, then a string in caps, space, EMERGENCY, comma, number, newline tilda

Experiment here: https://regex101.com/

Next time post your attempts

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The caveat is that 'EMERGENCY' won't be present every time.  The client can be different every single time.  It would need to be a wildcard search on the second line.  And it was my mistake to include the comma in the second line of the grouping.  The line would actually reflect something like:
MIDWEST EMERGENCY 92345434

Comment: reflect something like what?
If emergency isn't present each time just replace that part with [A-Z]+

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the "Extended" mode of Find (or Find and Replace) you should be able to use a combination of `\n` (for Unix format files) or `\r\n` (for DOS/Windows format files) to match one newline character. It should then be possible to put the rest of your search pattern before or after that token to search across multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
~\n([^~]*)\n~
```

Matches the tilda, newline, then anything that doesn't have a tilda in it before the next new line character and tilda.

The parenthesis around the [^~]* bind it to /1 if you want to use that

Answer (score 0):

[~]\r\n[^~]

This did the trick.  Thanks for all of the suggestions above.